# Using a pre-loaded icon

Tags: java, netbeans-8, imageicon

I'm using the following to show a cross in a label, that accompanies an if statement.

JLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "Resource/cross.png"));

Instead of loading the icon everytime I would prefer to have it imported into my project and call it from there.  I know how to import it but how do I modify the line of code above to point to the imported icon.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a static loader methode (in an utility class) and store it there

```
private static Map<String, Icon> lookUpMap = new HashMap<>();
public static Icon getImageIcon(String res){
    Icon icon = lookUpMap.get(res);
    if(icon = null){
        icon = new ImageIcon(res);
        lookUpMap.put(res, icon);
    }
    return icon;
}
```

you can access the icons now everywhere

```
JLabel.setIcon(UtilitClass.getImageIcon(path + "Resource/cross.png));
```

Comment: honestly: if your app is kind of bigger and you can't guarantee that your images are within your app you might consider if you don't want to wrap the Image access inside a factory class. that would help you later when you want to test or want to use different utility classes